# OpenGL: Put an "image" into the scene

Tags: opengl, mesh

I am trying to put an pre-saved intensity map into the scene. Each pixel of the the intensity map (u, v) has two values: z(height) and intensity.Since each pixel has a z value, simply putting a 2D image into the scene won't work.

The most intuitive idea is to draw it as a pointcloud(a group of points), but this method doesn't utilize the fact that the distance between each pixel is fixed.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If the intensity is an integer you can use the alpha component of the color. You can use 8/16/32 bits color components if your GL driver accepts them.

You can always set a generic buffer, arranged as u,v,z,i, u,v,z,i, ... and operate with it in a shader.

If the "points" form an ordered grid (same distance between them) you just need z and intensity values. The "distance between" can be passed as an uniform to the shaders.